# Deploying Winforms Application to Client Machines Application Failing on start

Tags: vb.net, winforms, deployment

This is Edited from the OP. This is a VB .NET 4.0 WinForms application. There is a mysql datasource involved with this project. The target CPU is set to any. Problem: When running this application on any computer that has VS 2010 installed along with the mysql connector it runs flawlessly. When installing on a virgin system(ie. No developer environment installed) but that machine does have .net framework 4.0 installed and a mysql server without the connector installed the application falls immediately. So to fix the issue I install the mysql connector MSI. This immediately fixes the issue on the client system and it runs. The problems is that as you can see below from my Installer setup that the 2 needed DLL files for MYSQL are actually included in the installation package so should not need to be installed separately. So Why is it that using that installer from the images do I need to install the mysql connector? Any Ideas? Below is a screen shot of the References the program uses and from what I believe I do not need to deploy any of those DLL files with my application other than the 2 MYSQL DLL files. So why is this failing?? Below are images showing the project references as well as the Installer Files that are being installed in the applicaiton folder. As shown in the image the 2 mysql dll files are to be put in the application folder. There is also a screen shot showing each dll's properties for in application folder.

[image: References]
[image: Application Installation Files]
[image: MySQL.Data.DLL Settings]
[image: MySQL.Data.Entity.DLL Settings]

Comment: Do you have installed the Full Framework or the Client Framework?

Comment: I did the .NET 4.0 Framework online install from microsoft on the client machine. It should be noted that this was developed on a Windows 7 Machine and I am trying to deploy on a client windows 7 machine so there is not big variable in that aspect.

Comment: You have two downloads [Full](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) or [Client](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24872)

Comment: Which one should I be using to help take care of this possibility?

Comment: Im downloading [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718] will that be suffice?

Comment: Ok so I just tested other small apps that do not use MYSQL on the virgin system and they all run without problem.. So that leaves me to believe it is something to do with the MYSQL.dll files.. I am not getting a provider error or any of that so that means the application is failing before it tries to actually use the database.

Comment: Windows pops a "Application Has Stopped Working" Message right after the splash screen starts to load...

Comment: Yes that is the Full Framework.  May be a problem with the [MySQL Connector Installer](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60263)

Comment: It is the MySQL Connector... I just Installed the Connector on that Computer and the application loads without problem... So I guess I will have to load the connector msi in with my setup program.. Using MYSQL for a database in deployable client apps has become a very big burden.. Is there a more viable option for a database that stores information that will only be used locally and is Entity Framework compatible?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that. You should ask that as a seperate question. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.

> but that machine does have .net framework 4.0 installed and a mysql server **without the connector installed** the application falls immediately.

You don't need to install the connector msi package, but you do need to include the two DLL files in the application's directory. Anytime you have some dependency, you need to deploy it with your application.

**Edit** solution quoted from my comment:

> From your update it sounds like you have a version mismatch on the
>   assemblies, and the references are set to Specific Version = True.
>   Check the version number of the assemblies on your developer machine
>   in the output directory, and check the version you are installing on
>   the client system. (You can just hover over the DLL to read the
>   version on the ToolTip). You can try to set Specific Version to false
>   by right clicking your reference and selecting properties, or simply
>   ensure you deploy the same version of assemblies. Your program is
>   looking for the versions its compiled against

Comment: please see the above edited post for details of where I am at present. What you mentioned about the dependencies I was kind of already up on that one.. As you can see from the images the application installer has both DLL Files being sent to the Application Folder.. It should be noted that the installer setup shown is the same exact one that I have had problems with needing to install the mysql connector. There have been no changes made so I have to be missing something little here because it is doing what I believe it should be.